# Azure ARM template -- how to scale out to exactly 2 instances?

Tags: azure, azure-rm-template, azure-app-service-plans, azure-appservice

I want to scale to a specific instance count.

I have the following in my template:

```
{
  "type": "Microsoft.Web/serverfarms",
  "apiVersion": "2018-02-01",
  "name": "[parameters('name')]",
  "location": "[variables('location')]",
  "sku": {
    "name": "[parameters('sku_name')]",
    "capacity": "[parameters('sku_capacity')]"
  },
  "kind": "app",
  "properties": {
    "perSiteScaling": false,
    "maximumElasticWorkerCount": 1,
    "isSpot": false,
    "reserved": false,
    "isXenon": false,
    "hyperV": false,
    "targetWorkerCount": 0,
    "targetWorkerSizeId": 0
  }
}
```

sku_capacity is set to 2, but it is not working. Nothing takes effect. How can I configure this correctly?

Also, if I set this in the Azure interface, and export the template, the auto scale settings does not seem to be included. Why?

Comment: I think it should be `"targetWorkerCount": 2`*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One scenario where `capacity` changes will not take effect is if the [Pricing tier](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/app-service/windows/) that your App Service Plan is in does not support scaling out.

I have a Standard App Service Plan and the following template works well for me:

```
{
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "parameters": {
        "asp_name": {
            "defaultValue": "ASPResources",
            "type": "String"
        },
        "sku_capacity": {
            "defaultValue": 5,
            "type": "int"
        }
    },
    "variables": {},
    "resources": [
        {
            "type": "Microsoft.Web/serverfarms",
            "apiVersion": "2018-02-01",
            "name": "[parameters('asp_name')]",
            "location": "South India",
            "sku": {
                "name": "S1",
                "tier": "Standard",
                "size": "S1",
                "family": "S",
                "capacity": "[parameters('sku_capacity')]"
            },
            "kind": "app",
            "properties": {
                "perSiteScaling": false,
                "maximumElasticWorkerCount": 1,
                "isSpot": false,
                "reserved": false,
                "isXenon": false,
                "hyperV": false,
                "targetWorkerCount": 0,
                "targetWorkerSizeId": 0
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Other resources: [App Service limits](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/management/azure-subscription-service-limits#app-service-limits)